# How to check which permission sets includes a edit permission on a field?

Tags: permission-sets

I have made account number as read only field, using permission sets we are giving edit access to selected users.
With the time we have got redundant permission sets giving same permissions.

permission set 1
permission set 2
permission set 3

all doing the same thing. To get rid of duplicate permission sets, I want to find out which permission sets provide edit access on a particular fields.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can query for this in [FieldPermissions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_fieldpermissions.htm):

```
select parent.name from fieldpermissions where field = 'account.accountnumber' and permissionsedit = true and parent.isownedbyprofile = false
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox